# Fade image after set time to reveal menu

Tags: jquery, fade, gif, timed

Can I have an opening gif animation fade to expose a menu and a static logo ?  I want the fade timed to occur after the gif animation has had time to play once through.  Then it will dissolve out -or maybe better yet- crossfade to a menu and a static logo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an `<img>` element? If so:

- If you remove the `<img>` element, the page will reflow and the buttons will move up to "fill the gap".
- If you use `display: none` the image will not be visible and will take up no space (the page will reflow just as if you'd removed the `<img>`).
- If you use `visibility: hidden`, the `<img>` will be invisible, but will stay in place. The buttons will stay below the invisible image.

To remove an element or edit its CSS using JavaScript, you first need to get a reference to it. One way to do this is by giving it an `id` and using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById). You can then manipulate its [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style) or [remove it from the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Regarding detecting when the gif animation is finished: there is no way that I know of to detect this using JavaScript and regular gif `<img>` elements. You'll have to rely on a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). Because loading time varies per visitor, you could start the timeout when the image has [finished loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/image#a-onload):

```html
<img src="img/animation.gif" id="disappearing_image" />
```

```js
var img = document.getElementyById('disappearing_image');
var runtime = 1200; // in milliseconds

img.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(img).fadeOut("slow");
    }, runtime);
    img.onload = null;
};
```

This will fade out the image with the given `id` ("disappearing_image") after `runtime` milliseconds.

Note that I set the `onload` handler back to `null` once the event has been handled. This is  because Internet Explorer will fire this event first when the image is loaded, and then for **each frame** of the animation.

One last note: different browsers may load animated gifs differently. For example, one browser may load the entire file before starting the animation, while another could animate the image while it's loading, then trigger `onload` and animate it again. If you run into trouble, you could look into **preloading** your image (search for "[javascript] preload img" here on SO).

Comment: Cool.  setTimeout looks like it would do it.  I had been considering fading in a transparent image as a delay tactic.  I was just going to set enough time for the animation to complete for a low speed connection.  It wouldn't be a heavy gif.  I wonder.. if I fade up an animated gif, will it play after fully faded or try to play during the fade?  And would this then act like a preload?

Comment: It would play during the fade. but its better IMO, you let it play first by giving runtime, then fade it. Uh, depends, your choice.

Comment: If you still get doubts the best thing would be make a fiddle and try to play with it.